# Proving $f^{-1}(S \cap T) = f^{-1}(S) \cap f^{-1}(T)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Proving $f^{-1}(S \cap T)  = f^{-1}(S) \cap f^{-1}(T)$

There are a lot of proofs available on the website for the same identity, but I have done it a bit differently. I am new to Set theory and functions, guide me if I am wrong.

> Definition : Let $f: A \rightarrow B$, then   $f^{-1}(B) = \{a \in A | f(a) \in B \}$

Now,
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(S \cap T) &=    \{a \in A | f(a) \in S \cap T \} \\
&\Leftrightarrow  \{a \in A | f(a) \in S \wedge f(a) \in T \}\\
& = a \in A \wedge f(a) \in S \wedge f(a) \in T\\ 
& \Leftrightarrow( a \in A \wedge f(a) \in S )\wedge (a \in A  \wedge  f(a) \in T)\\
& = f^{-1}(S) \cap f^{-1}(T)
\end{align*}

Comment: Why do you say wlog ? and why are there equivalences between sets ? And then equivalences between sets and formulas ? You've got the idea but you need to write it down better

Comment: Actually, I read up some similar proofs which used without loss of generality, to go from a set to a certain element. So I thought it might work out, and then I would use it again to generalize the set. I too think I need to work on it. How can I go about correcting the first line following WLOG?

Comment: Just remove the occurrences of "WLOG". They are not needed here. Also replace $\Leftrightarrow$ with $=$ when you have sets before and after.

Comment: I agree with md2perpe. And when you want to "go from sets to formulas", write something like "And $a\in X$ if and only if $\phi(a)$" (where $\phi$ is a formula)

Comment: Thank you! I have corrected the mistakes. @Max so I should rephrase the step in which I go from a set to a general term to, $a \in A \text{ iff } f(a) \in S \wedge f(a) \in T$ ?

Comment: Well here it's not $A$, it's rather $f^{-1}(S\cap T)$

Comment: A hint: Don't work with the $\{\}$ for set theoretic proofs. Nobody does this and it is confusing. I also did this in the beginning.

Comment: In your displayed lines, the second line should have an "$=$ "sign, not a "$\iff$". The third line should be "$=\{a\in A:f(a)\in S\}\cap \{a\in A:f(a)\in T\}$". And then delete the fourth line. And I agree with the advice in the comment from Math_QED.  It is easier to figure it out using "$x\in f^{-1}(S\cap T)\iff....$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof seem essentially correct, but seem to be confused by terminology.

First of all equivalency is about statements while equality is about objects (and sets are among objects). For this reason it's not feasible to mix statements and objects in the way you do. Either you stick to using objects like in $$f^{-1}(S\cap T)=\cdots=f^{-1}(S)\cap f^{-1}(T)$$ or statements like in $$x\in f^{-1}(S\cap T)\Leftrightarrow\cdots\Leftrightarrow x\in f^{-1}(S) \cap f^{-1})(T)$$

Both approaches are workable and follows the same steps as you used. For example:

$$\begin{align*}
x \in f^{-1}(S \cap T) 
&\Leftrightarrow f(x)\in S\cap T \\
&\Leftrightarrow f(x)\in S \land f(x)\in T\\ 
&\Leftrightarrow x\in f^{-1}(S) \land x\in f^{-1}(T) \\
&\Leftrightarrow x\in f^{-1}(S) \cap f^{-1}(T)
\end{align*}$$

Second the use of the phrase "without loss of generality" is almost always used when you only prove the theorem for a subdomain of it's validity, but the nature of the situation is such that the rest of the domain of the theorem either follows from the subdomain or that of symmetry reasons the proof will work for all other subdomains. Sometimes it's also used if the theorem is trivial for some special cases.

As you see I've excluded the part that $x\in A$ in the proof above. If we don't regard that this is trivially implied or assumed we could have used the phrase there by assuming $x\in A$ without loss of generality (since for the case $x\notin A$ it's trivial since $x\notin f(U)$ for any set $U$ then).

Comment: Thank you so much! I was too confused, how to go from set builder notation to a statement involving logical connectives. This is very clear, although I am not able to understand what you are trying to say in the last paragraph. Are you saying, we also need to prove $x \in A \iff x \in A$ but it is trivial and we can say without loss of generality?

Comment: What I meant was that according to your definition $x\in f^{-1}(S)$ is the same as $x\in A \land f(x)\in S$. I could easily have put that into the statements, but in order to have an example of "WLOG" I decided to keep them out (making the proof formally valid only if $x\in A$).

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! I won't have nightmares now. :)